# How to save workbook without showing save dialog with Excel interop?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, save, office-interop

I have to create a Console application that exports a `DataSet` to Excel. The problem is that it shouldn't pop up the save window, it should automatically create the Excel file. So far I have the following code, but I don't know how to make it save automatically. Would appreciate any help.

```
public static void CreateWorkbook(DataSet ds, String path)
{
    int rowindex = 0;
    int columnindex = 0;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application wapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbook;

    wapp.Visible = false;

    wbook = wapp.Workbooks.Add(true);
    wsheet = (Worksheet)wbook.ActiveSheet;

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            wsheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName;

        }

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            rowindex++;
            columnindex = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                columnindex++;
                wsheet.Cells[rowindex + 1, columnindex] = row[col.ColumnName];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String err = ex.Message;
    }
    wapp.UserControl = true;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

All of the arguments to `WorkBook.SaveAs()` are optional, but you can just use `Type.Missing` for most of them if you want to.

The typical call would look like:

```
wbook.SaveAs("c:\\temp\\blah", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wbook.Close();
```

Note that I didn't include the file extension; Excel will set that for you.

[Workbook.SaveAs Method (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel) | Microsoft Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=VS.100).aspx) describes each of the arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Try to call the `SaveAs` method of the workbook. For the lot of parameter, try to pass `Type.Missing` to all parameters but the first ( the file name ).

Comment: ya i tried that but it takes so many: 
parameters void SaveAs(object Filename, object FileFormat, object Password, object WriteResPassword, object ReadOnlyRecommended, object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, object ConflictResolution, object AddToMru, object TextCodepage, object TextVisualLayout, object Local); 
that i dont know how to use it...

Comment: I think just the first two are mandatory, all the other can be used as missing parameters.

Comment: so what would a "object Filename" be? can you give me an example

Comment: @ha1: just use a string. `Object` is the base type for _all_ other .NET types, so you can pass any type in place of an `Object` type argument.

Answer (score 5):

Add `ConflictResolution` to `XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges`
and set the application's `DisplayAlerts` property to `false` so the window won't show.

```
m_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

// Quit Excel and clean up.
m_xlWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename: m_xlFilePath, FileFormat: excelFileExtension,
Password: false, ReadOnlyRecommended: XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
ConflictResolution: XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges);  

m_xlWorkbook.Close();
```

see [XlSaveConflictResolution Enum (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) | Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlsaveconflictresolution.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.saveas%28v=office.11%29.aspx#Y114)

```
wbook.SaveAs(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
wapp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

setting [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx) property to `false` will stop displaying all alerts for all of its workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `open xml sdk` to generate documents instead of automation; it is much more reliable.

Comment: could you please more details to the response and the solution

Answer (score 2):

Use the DisplayAlerts property. Its very simple and fast.

```
private void SaveAs(Excel.Workbook WorkBook, string FileName)
    {
        m_Saving = true;
        try
        {
            if (Global.CreatingCopy)
                this.ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            WorkBook.SaveAs(FileName);
        }
        finally
        {
            m_Saving = false;
            if (this.ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts == false)
                this.ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
        }
    }
```

Never let the Excel define the kind of file when you're going to save the file. Because it's possible that the format will be changed.

If original doc was .xls and the current user has the office 2013 the default format its .xlsx and then the Excel will convert the file to .xlsx and the users tha doesnt have the Excel 2010 or superior cant open the file.