# Need to create Excel file and save in local path. in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, file, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have this Code...but it ask for save file or open file option in one dialog box.

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=XYZ.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", attachment);
.....
.....
```

i want to generate excel dynamic using my code and save in local folder in my drive.

Comment: Be a little more specific and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You need to reframe the question. From what I understand, you want to generate excel file and save directly without showing the "save file" dialog in a browser.

Comment: i have tried that i put in my question....i want to save file without opening save and open dialog box.

Comment: @sankoobaba yes correct

Comment: This post could help, please check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012705/excel-interop-saving-workbook-without-showing-save-dialog

Comment: i have written all the code in .aspx page in my project. so i want to save it using aspx page in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not allowed, for good reasons. First of all when you try to save a file from a web application on someone else's computer you have no idea whether the folder in which you try to save the file exists and whether the user has access to this folder. Also the webapplication does not know if the computer that is being used is a Windows computer, Mac, Linux or maybe a telephone, for which all filesystems work different. Second, and more importantly, it is a huge risk if a website was able to save a file to any folder, for example your start-up folder. A malicious website would be able to install viruses/keylogger/etc. on your computer without you knowing it.

So if you want to save an Excel file to a specific folder you must make a console application or a Windows application.