# Disable Interop.Excel's Default Save Prompt on Close

Tags: c#

i'm saving a bunch of calculated data into an excel file using

```
if (result == DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            xl.DisplayAlerts = false;
            wb.SaveAs(fn, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value,
            Missing.Value, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

            wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xl.Quit();

            releaseObject(ws);
            releaseObject(wb);
            releaseObject(xl);
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xl.Quit();
            releaseObject(ws);
            releaseObject(wb);
            releaseObject(xl);
        }
```

everything is working fine when i press `OK`, but if i `CANCEL` the save, then another "generic" save window shows up?  I have no other `SaveFileDialogs` in the project, my assumption is that it comes from the Excel object save file dialog, but i really don't know how can i get rid of this?

`xl` is the `interop` object, `ws` the worksheet and `wb` the workbook

TA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel interop: saving workbook without showing save dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012705/excel-interop-saving-workbook-without-showing-save-dialog)

Comment: not a duplicate!  i want the save dialog, just not the second save dialog.  that thread is about workbook.SaveAs (which i'm already using).  Thanks for the research though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set 'Saved' property of workbook's object to true before calling Close method.

Like so:

```
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            wb.Saved = true;
            wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xl.Quit();
            releaseObject(ws);
            releaseObject(wb);
            releaseObject(xl);
        }
```

Hope this would help.