# Working with Excel and trying to find a save workbook method in c# but no luck; I have exhausted google

Tags: c#, excel

This program is for a church food pantry, and I am doing it for free. My experience with C# is none, but I took the project because it sounds fun as I love to program. Anyway, my problem is I need to save the workbook before I close it, and I can't seem to figure out a way to do that.

The code and a few tries are listed here; the error I received is listed next to the try.

```
    private void btnExcelClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        exApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // this.Save(); CS1961 Form1 does not contain a defintion for 'Save' and no accesible extension method
        // thisworkbook.save(); CS0103 The name 'Thisworkbook' does not exist in the current contex
       // Excel.Workbook.save(); CS0117 Workbook does not contain a definition for 'save'
       // exApp.Workbooks.Save(); CS1061 'Workbooks' does not contain a defintion for 'Save' and no accesible extension method
        exApp.Workbooks.Close();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D%5Bvba%5D+save+workbook and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D%5Bvba%5D+saveas Doesn't look to me like you've *exhausted google*.

Comment: try this maybe ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012705/how-to-save-workbook-without-showing-save-dialog-with-excel-interop

Comment: Several tries weren't listed; I didn't think of listing them till after.

Comment: The way they did the Save as won't work because Save is not a member of workbooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Workbook class that implements the Save() and SaveAs() methods.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-save-workbooks?view=vs-2019

A few things to understand about C#: the keyword **this** has specific meaning to the class being used. And C# is case-sensitive.

Let's look at why your few tries have failed.

`this.Save(); CS1961 Form1 does not contain a defintion for 'Save' and no accesible extension method`

The above failed because **this** refers to your form class, not a Workbook object.

`thisworkbook.save(); CS0103 The name 'Thisworkbook' does not exist in the current contex`

Apparently you do not have a variable named `thisworkbook`.

`Excel.Workbook.save(); CS0117 Workbook does not contain a definition for 'save'`

The error is because you spelled `save` in lowercase, when it should be mixed `Save`.  If you correct this, it will give you another error because `Excel.Workbook` does not refer to a specific Workbook.  Maybe try `ActiveWorkbook`.

`exApp.Workbooks.Save(); CS1061 'Workbooks' does not contain a defintion for 'Save' and no accesible extension method`

Here you used the plural `Workbooks` which is a collection and it does not have a `Save` method.  You must refer to a individual Workbook.  Try `exApp.Workbooks[0].Save()`.